# Are "kotlin-android" and "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" the same?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I see the following two Gradle plugins being used interchangeably in a project:

```kt
    plugins {
        id("kotlin-android")
    }
```

```kt
    plugins {
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    }
```

Are they the same?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Refer to library `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31`.

Both `kotlin-android.properties` and `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.properties` link to plugin `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPluginWrapper` which means that they are the same.

Comment: web URLs for reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: May I ask how can you figure out what library these ids refer to? Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: To supplement the answer, here is the [link](https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.31/) to the related plugin. Download and extracts the jar file, you can find both `kotlin-android.properties` and `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.properties` in `META-INF/gradle-plugins`. Inside both files, `implementation-class` points to `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPluginWrapper`, thus the conclusion.

Comment: you can also find them in the source [v1.5.31](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/v1.5.31/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins). But as the under answer said, in latest source [v1.9.0.RC](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts), you can only find "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" plugin

Answer (score 8):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70299118/1955202) does still hold true, however, I would like to point out that since Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 there is an assistant available that auto-adds Kotlin to projects. That assistant uses `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'` (even if you already have `kotlin-android` in the very same gradle file - quite annoyingly.

I assume somebody thought of this, maybe `kotlin-android` will be deprecated in the near future? For now, the answer to your question is: they are the same but probably `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` is slightly preferred

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin plugins can be referenced by multiple plugin IDs. The Android team recommends using the namespaced plugin ID, and refactor from shorthand to namespaced plugin ID by the following table:

[image]

[Source](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl#find-plugin-id)

Answer (score 2):

For the kotlin gradle DSL

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") // or com.android.library
    kotlin("android")
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-understand-project-structure.html#android-application